# fail2ban with haproxy logs how to to block

Tags: fail2ban

Hi Team,
                First of all thanks for you investing precious time to help for beginners like me .

I have installed failed 2 ban in centos

in my haproxy logs

```
Mar  7 02:37:07 localhost haproxy[9378]: 115.xxx.xxx.xxx:19004 [07/Mar/2015:02:37:03.823] http-ingress testing/new-server 2952/0/0/17/3242 302 689 - - --VN 3/3/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /myadmin/scripts/setup.php HTTP/1.1"
```

how to block

I have done below steps if any mistake pls correct it

===========================================================

Command:

```
vim /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/vulscan.conf
```

File:

```
[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST>.*\"GET

ignoreregex =


[vulscan]

enabled = true

port = http,https

filter = vulscan

banaction = iptables-allports

logpath = /var/log/haproxy_0.log

#action   = hostsdeny[file=/etc/hosts.deny]

action = iptables-multiport[name=vulscan,port="http,https", protocol=tcp]

maxretry = 1

bantime = 604800
```

=====================================================================

Command:

```
iptables -L
```

Ouput pasted below:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-vulscan  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports http,https 
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-vulscan (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 0):

use this 
failregex = haproxy[\d+]:

and you can check your regex with haproxy log by running 
fail2ban-regex [haproxy_log] [fail2ban_haproxy.conf]

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer to the original old question but will hopefully get anyone started on using Docker, Fail2Ban and Haproxy together.
I spent quite a while figuring it out and it does work at the time of writing in 2022.

The files listed here are mainly the core parts necessary for this specific task, most haproxy, fail2ban and docker files will have much more info.

**haproxy.cfg** - this sets up super simple logging and sets certain paths to 403 denied for bots that we will look for later

```
global
  log stdout local0 debug

defaults
  log global
  option httplog
  log-format "%Tl|%ci-%ST-%r"

frontend input-main-web
  bind *:80
  bind *:443 ssl crt /astro/ssl-certs
  option forwardfor header X-Real-IP
  http-request set-header X-Real-IP %[src]
  
  # attempting to deny bots to anywhere
  acl bot-path path -i -m sub wp-includes
  acl bot-path path -i -m sub wp-login
  acl bot-path path -i -m sub xmlrpc
  acl bot-path path -i -m sub wordpress
  http-request deny if bot-path
```

**haproxy Dockerfile** - this logs stdout to an actual file fail2ban can read (this will be the last line, if using haproxy inside docker)

```
CMD haproxy -W -db -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg | tee /var/log/haproxy.log 2>&1
```

**fail2ban.yml** - this will run fail2ban nicely in its own container and yet still protect the host machine and all the containers runnning on it

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  astro-fail2ban:
    build: ./fail2ban
    image: astro-fail2ban
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/docker-data/fail2ban:/data
      - /home/docker-log/haproxy:/log:ro
      - /var/log/secure:/var/log/secure:ro
    environment: 
      - TZ=America/Phoenix
      - F2B_DB_PURGE_AGE=30d
      - F2B_LOG_TARGET=/data/fail2ban.log
      - F2B_LOG_LEVEL=INFO
      - F2B_IPTABLES_CHAIN=INPUT

    network_mode: "host"

    privileged: true
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - NET_RAW
```

**fail2ban Dockerfile** - copy the custom files you are creating

```
FROM crazymax/fail2ban:latest

RUN mkdir -p /var/log
RUN touch /var/log/auth.log

RUN mkdir -p /etc/fail2ban
COPY ./jail.local /etc/fail2ban/
COPY ./haproxy.conf /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/
COPY ./docker-action.conf /etc/fail2ban/action.d/
```

**jail.local** - this tells fail2ban to look thru the haproxy log for the filter defined and perform the custom ban action on any it finds (can set findtime and bantime to your own spec)

```
[haproxy]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = haproxy
logpath = /log/haproxy.log
maxretry = 3
findtime = 300
bantime = 1800
banaction = docker-action
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1
```

**haproxy.conf** - tells fail2ban to look for the 403 status code in the log  (our bot signal)

```
[INCLUDES]
# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf

[Definition]
_daemon = haproxy
failregex = \|<HOST>-403
ignoreregex =
```

**docker-action.conf** - the custom ban actions which work on the forward chain and drop packets - a bit magic, but does work effectively

```
[Definition]
 
actionstart = iptables -N f2b-haproxy
              iptables -A f2b-haproxy -j RETURN
              iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-haproxy
 
actionstop = iptables -D FORWARD -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-haproxy
             iptables -F f2b-haproxy
             iptables -X f2b-haproxy
 
actioncheck = iptables -n -L FORWARD | grep -q 'f2b-haproxy[ \t]'
 
actionban = iptables -I f2b-haproxy 1 -s <ip> -j DROP
 
actionunban = iptables -D f2b-haproxy -s <ip> -j DROP
```

Any more questions ... leave a comment.